Can we promote cryptography-related events on this site?
Since a lot of people interested in cryptography visit crypto.stackexchange.com every day, I think that it is a very good place to promote crypto events.
Maybe it would be possible by submitting some ads to the self-promotion question? But even in this case, I don't think it is the more appropriate way, because the information needs to be spread in a short period of time...
So, there is some way to promote such events in Crypto Exchange?

I see three options to promote such events.

Make a meta post. Make a post here on meta documenting the existence of this event and briefly summarize what it is about, where and when it is. You may also ask our mod team (via chat or comments) for the featured which will make the post pop up on the main site. This is especially practical if you have a medium preparation time (a few days at least) and if the event is important enough to warrant the attention.
Drop a line in the Side Channel. This is practical especially if the preparation time is short (a few hours up to one day) and / or if the event is of minor importance. Note that mods (and room owners) can also pin stars in the chat, so they rest longer than they usually would (although this isn't a problem in the Side Channel).
Make a community promotion ad. This is the way of choice if you have a long prepration time (a few weeks at least). You can post a (simple) picture in this question as answer and once it reaches +6 score, it will be displayed on the main site. An example for this would be the BIU winter school which was promoted in 2015 and was scheduled for early 2016.

Note please that you may want to make clear when an event is over, i.e. by removing (or renewing?) the community ad and / or placing a fat headline in your meta.crypto.se post saying "this event is over, look here for the next one".

About the third option: may this picture be posted any time? Or is there some deadline?

@Vitor, yes, you have to post the picture this year (on the 2016 post, next year on the 2017 post), otherwise there isn't and it is apparently a largely automated process as I only yesterday changed something on our (only) deployed ad and the change is already live (I https'ed the image link)

+1 for #3. Combine that with #2, i.e. come over to the chat room and ask people to please vote for your answer so that it makes the threshold :) That combination is probably the best, though the Winter School last year did well in getting votes.
